# How to add an extra, static thumb label to an angular material slider (mat-slider)?

Tags: angular-material, mat-slider

I'd like the users to be able to see the original value of the slider as a reference point as they select a new value.

So I'd like to add an extra thumb label (351) like this:
[image: material slider with extra thumb label]

I know this isn't supported by the mat-slider in the [documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/slider/overview), but I'm wondering if there's a hacky way to do this.  I'm new to angular material and not super strong in css.

Or maybe there are other component libraries/alternative implementations that would support this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how to update/hack angular material to do this.

But I did find one [slider implementation from NG-Zorro](https://ng.ant.design/components/slider/en) that has support for labels (or "marks" as they call them).

[image: slider with marks from ng zorro]

Other libraries that I looked at that did *not* support this:

- https://material.angular.io/components/slider/overview
- https://clarity.design/documentation/range#examples
- https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/slider
- https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components
- https://edcarroll.github.io/ng2-semantic-ui/#/getting-started
- https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/documentation